# Why does slice not rendered in sliceviewer apk when setPrimaryAction is not used in the row builder

Tags: android, android-slices

I am not able to display the slice in slice viewer app when the setPrimaryAction is not set in the row builder

```
    list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY)
    {
        header {
            title ="News Content"
        }
        row {
            title = "news genre"
            subtitle = "first new headlines"
        }            
    }
```

**The above snippet does not display slice in sliceviewer**

whereas if I change the code by adding primaryAction in one of the row. Slice is getting rendered but for my usecase, I don't want to set any action

```
    list(context, sliceUri, ListBuilder.INFINITY)        
    {
        header {
            title ="News Content"
        }
        row {
            title = "news genre"
            subtitle = "first new headlines"
            setPrimaryAction = SliceAction.create(
             PendingIntent.getActivity(
             context, 0, Intent(context, MyActivityClass::class.java), 0
             ),         
             IconCompat.createWithResource(context,
              R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
             ListBuilder.ICON_IMAGE,
             "Open App"
             )
        }
  }
```

**The above snippet displays slice in sliceviewer**

I would like to understand why do we need to set primaryAction. There might be few use-cases where we don't need any action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Android's official documentation, Slice actions are considered as the most basic element of the slice template.

So when we don't set the primary action , the following exception occurs

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: A slice requires a primary action; ensure one of your builders has called #setPrimaryAction with a valid SliceAction.**

The purpose of slices are to help users perform tasks faster by enabling engagement outside of the fullscreen app experience. Since it is user interactive, I guess that's why they have mandated a basic action.